# Is in Tensorflow 2.x we aren't need to specify the input shape?

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I just read the official tutorial [in this page](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/advanced). And the code example to create a model is below:

```
class MyModel(Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')
    self.flatten = Flatten()
    self.d1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')
    self.d2 = Dense(10, activation='softmax')

  def call(self, x):
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.flatten(x)
    x = self.d1(x)
    return self.d2(x)

# Create an instance of the model
model = MyModel()
```

My question is, why in the code above we didn't need to specify an input shape in the first layer (Conv2D)? Is there any official documentation that mention this behaviour?

Because if I read the official docs about [Conv Layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D) it said:

> When using this layer as the first layer in a model, provide the keyword argument input_shape (tuple of integers, does not include the sample axis), e.g. input_shape=(128, 128, 3) for 128x128 RGB pictures in data_format="channels_last"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is working as intended.

Convolution as an operation works regardless of the input shape. Just the channels of the input needs to match.
You can see this behavior work as expected in tf.nn.conv2d. (Which is what your code snippet is using)

Now, you are linking a reference to keras.conv2d which forces the user to specify input shape to make the code more readable and 'validate' user input.

Comment: yes it works normally, I've also try to remove input shape in dense layer for simple NN, and it works too. But, is there any official documentation that mention this behaviour?

Comment: Looks like during a layer call if the input_shape is set to none or is different from the current input, the convolution operation is redefined based on the current input. Documentation is in the code in the link below under **Conv.call()**


https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.1/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/convolutional.py#L188-L194